# Not calling a datatable row based on field

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have inherited a piece of code (below). From the list items it populates I wanted to NOT populate a row of which I know the 'variant' is #AAB.

Is there a way to populate the table in the same way, but ignore the row with variant AAB ??

```
public void BuildList()
{
    DataTable variants = Common.GetAllVariantsFromDB(modelCode);
    variantsList.InnerHtml += "<span id=\"variant\">" + Common.GetVariantInfo(variant)[0] + "</span>";
    variantsList.InnerHtml += "<ul id=\"variantsList\">";
    for (int i = 0; i < variants.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        variantsList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href=\"#" + variants.Rows[i]["Variant"].ToString() + "\">" + variants.Rows[i]["EngineSize"].ToString()</a></li>";
    }
    variantsList.InnerHtml += "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding condition like below will filter the items

```
 for (int i = 0; i < variants.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
          if(variants.Rows[i]["Variant"].ToString()!="#AAB")
            variantsList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href=\"#" + variants.Rows[i]["Variant"].ToString() + "\">" + variants.Rows[i]["EngineSize"].ToString()</a></li>";
        }
```

Comment: Many thank, for ref (to you all). The completed code will be posted below.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void BuildList()
{
    DataTable variants = Common.GetAllVariantsFromDB(modelCode);
    variantsList.InnerHtml += "<span id=\"variant\">" + Common.GetVariantInfo(variant)[0] + "</span>";
    variantsList.InnerHtml += "<ul id=\"variantsList\">";
    for (int i = 0; i < variants.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (variants.Rows[i]["Variant"].ToString() != "GJ1")
        {
            variantsList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href=\"#" + variants.Rows[i]["Variant"].ToString() + "\">" + variants.Rows[i]["EngineSize"].ToString()</a></li>";
        }
    }
    variantsList.InnerHtml += "</ul>";
}
```